# Facing problem in java code while running in terminal

Tags: java

** I am Trying to print this pattern in JAVA 
a/2 + a/3 + a/4 ....+ a/n
**

Here is my java code

```
import java.util.*;
public class ser
{
public static void main(String args[]){
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the value of a and n");
int a,i,n;
double s=0;
a=in.nextInt();
n=in.nextInt();
for(i=1;i<n;i++)
s=s+(double)a/(i+1);
System.out.println("ssss = "+s);
}
}
```

**I'm using Kali linux and today I'm facing this error while running my java code in terminal**

```
Enter the value of a and n
a 12
```

Error:

````
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
        at ser.main(one.java:9)```
````

Comment: Did you enter "a" as value of a? That's not the integer the code expects.

Comment: It seems you have entered the letter `a` for the value of *a*. That woin’t work. You need to enter a number for *a*.

Comment: if I only enter the value of a  , Enter the value of a and n
4 like this then code is not running

Comment: did you give input as "a 12" ? both should be integer.

Comment: Please format your code. Also, please follow java convertions: classes start with a capital letter.

Comment: if I do this then <br /> one.java:9: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int
a=in.nextLine();
             ^
1 error
error: compilation failed

Comment: give input like this (without using quote) :
12 12

Answer (score -1, accepted):

brother!! just hardcore "a" to the print statement instead for taking it as an input.
may be this code will help u

```
    import java.util.*;
    public class ser
      {
          public static void main(String args[]){
          Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
          System.out.println("Enter the value of  n");
          int i,n;
          n=in.nextInt();
          for(i=2;i<=n;i++)
          {
                System.out.print("a/"+i);
                if(i==n)
                      break;
                else
                   System.out.print(" + ");
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: No, the OP wants to accept two inputs and use both of them. They're trying to print the *values* of a/2, a/3 etc.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem<sup>1</sup> with your code.

The problem is with the input that you are giving to the program.

Assuming that you are running from the command line, the way to compile and run the program is like this.

```
steve@greybeast:/tmp$ javac ser.java
steve@greybeast:/tmp$ java ser
Enter the value of a and n
2 12
ssss = 4.206421356421357
steve@greybeast:/tmp$
```

See?

When it asks me to "enter a and n", I type `2 12 <ENTER>`.

And it works (as far as I can tell).

What you have been doing is entering letters, numbers in quotation marks and other things.  But the program as you have written it<sup>2</sup> *expects* only 2 integers with whitespace between them.  And when it gets something that it doesn't expect, the `nextInt()` call throws an `InputMismatchException`.

---

<sup>1 - Actually, there is a problem.  Your code ignores a number of important Java style conventions.  For example, class names should NOT start with a lowercase letter, and code should be correctly indented.  But these things only matter to humans who have to read your code.

2 - I hope that >you< wrote it.  'Cos if you copied it rather than writing it yourself, you are cheating yourself of the *opportunity* to learn to program.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with your input. Code is expecting integer value as input and you are providing 'a'. You need to provide integer.

Comment: Bro will you please help me with this code I'm not able to understand, I'm not familiar with Java !! Help me with the code

Comment: @Nishant - There is no problem with your code.  The problem is with your input.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to provide a and then 12, just provide 12, press enter and then provide the next Integer. Right now I think it's trying to decode a as an integer. Just provide the integers in order of their input and it should work.

Comment: bro If I provide value of a first then it throw this error Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
        at Ser.main(one.java:9)
 or <br /> If I give both as a interger then it add both !! Will you please help me with code ? I'm not very much familier with Java

Answer (score -1):

To clear confusion, I modified your code as below.

Provide your input in two separate lines.

```
import java.util.*;
public class ser
{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the value of a and n");
        int a, i, n;
        String a1, n1;
        double s = 0;
        a1 = in.nextLine(); // Reading as string value the complete line
        n1 = in.nextLine();
        // checking whether the value acquired is number or not
        if (!isNumeric(a1.toString())) {
            System.out.println("Please provide a valid number without alphbets or symbol, you have typed:" + a1);
            System.exit(0);
        }
        if (!isNumeric(n1.toString())) {
            System.out.println("Please provide a valid number without alphbets or symbol, you have typed:" + n1);
            System.exit(0);
        }
        a = Integer.parseInt(a1);
        n = Integer.parseInt(n1);
        for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
            s = s + (double) a / (i + 1);
        System.out.println("ssss = " + s);
    }

    // will check whether the string passed is number or not
    public static boolean isNumeric(String strNum) {
        if (strNum == null) {
            return false;
        }
        try {
            double d = Double.parseDouble(strNum);
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Without *explaining* the changes in code, this is unlikely to help much. I'd also suggest reformatting the whole thing - it's very hard to read at the moment, with an extra line between each line of code, and inconsistent indentation.

Comment: I don't think a separate comments or documentation required for this code. It is very simple one

Comment: Well you might think that, but I can say with rather a lot of experience of Stack Overflow that "code-only" answers with no explanation of the code are rarely deemed particularly useful. (And likewise, poorly formatted code isn't as useful as well-formatted code.)

Comment: So that is the reason you unliked the answer. Just for formatting.

Comment: I added comments, let me know anything is required

Comment: I haven't voted on the answer one way or another, and I'd advise against making assumptions about voting behavior. The formatting is still terrible though - why have a blank line between each actual line of code? Use blank lines where they're genuinely useful. And this is *still* a nearly-code-only answer - I was suggesting adding *explanatory text*, which is usually more useful than just comments in code. (It's fine to keep comments as well, but the explanatory text is the most important part.)

Comment: Sorry for my assumption, but the extra spaces are being added by the vscode for formatting. I directly did a copy paste from there. I will remove the spaces manually now